# Heroku app timeout on boot (R10) - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, heroku, hapi.js

I am using process.env.PORT, and that shows in the logs (see below, localhost:40170, changing each time I run app). Also, load time is quick (10 sec), as I'm not running any build processes within node start. Running heroku local runs app fine. Please help me find what may be causing this issue.

Here's the logs:

`2018-05-03T02:37:04.505544+00:00 app[web.1]: loading routes from ./modules/user.login/auth.routes.js...
2018-05-03T02:37:04.526922+00:00 app[web.1]: loading routes from ./modules/user.login/login.routes.js...
2018-05-03T02:37:04.531738+00:00 app[web.1]: loading routes from ./modules/feature.clientes/clientes.crud.routes.js...
2018-05-03T02:37:04.542719+00:00 app[web.1]: loading routes from ./modules/feature.contratos/contratos.crud.routes.js...
2018-05-03T02:37:04.552200+00:00 app[web.1]: loading routes from ./modules/feature.servicos/servicos.crud.routes.js...
2018-05-03T02:37:04.601525+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running at: http://localhost:40170
2018-05-03T02:38:01.800290+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-05-03T02:38:01.800290+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-05-03T02:38:01.899194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-05-03T02:38:01.940085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

Comment: @Paul thats a good guess! Thanks for the tip, will try that and report back

Comment: @Paul bingo! 2 packages were installed globally on my machine. If you'd like to make an answer of it, I'll mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to know without seeing some of your code. If I had to guess, there’s a dependency you’re satisfying locally that you’re not satisfying on the server, like a DH connection or maybe you failed to include a module in your package.json that you have installed locally (eg a global install)

Comment: actually... no, it didn't work. Or, at least, there is something more to it. That prevented some message errors, but the server still crashes. I've also in the mean time created a new virtual machine from ground up, installed node and git, cloned it, npm installed it, npm started it, and it ran just fine. So I'm stuck in a dead end again

Answer (score 1):

Solved it: in addition to [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173562/3645375), there was something else.

I had changed the `host` option of my Hapi server from `'0.0.0.0'` to `'localhost'` (probably cause it wasn't running locally). According to [Hapi's API reference](https://hapijs.com/api#-serveroptionshost), this is done automatically - first it tries machine name, then 'localhost'.

So just removing that setting solved the problem. Now Heroku logs something like: `Server running at: http://243c893-1ec-48d-bdc4-2ba08a3d59:55296`

Answer (score 0):

```
This seems to be happen as because heroku sets dynamic port at which your app runs, as you are using PORT from env you need to add PORT in heroku config vars. Just got through heroku app => settings => view config vars => Add PORT <your port number example 5000> in it.
```

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, the env.PORT is used exactly so they can choose which is the best port to use. They set it in the environment and my code uses it